# How to use new client side Facebook notifications API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications

Official documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app_notifications/ says:

> 1. "Apps can send notifications to any existing user that has authorized the app. No special or extended permission is to required."
> 2. "All notifications from an app are treated the same way, independent of how it was sent - via this API or as a user-to-user
>      request."

Server side API works fine, but I've decided to call notification API directly from flash client. I've requested **{recipient_userid}/notifications** with all necessary stuff like client token etc.

First time I've received error 200. After applying **manage_notifications** permissions for application I've received new type of error 606 ("You do not have permission to fetch notifications for this user").

My question is it possible to send notifications through client side request to Graph API? Is additional permissions needed?

Comment: Are you trying to _fetch_ notifications (as the error message says), or are you trying to _send_ them? If the latter – sounds to me, like you made a GET instead of a POST request.

Comment: Not having a php example on that page really confuses

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from the fb docs:

> Note: Only apps on Facebook.com can use the Notifications API. Also these notifications are only surfaced on >desktop version of Facebook.com.

That means that when posting a notification, you must use an application access token - not the usual user access token.

You must first get the application access token:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Then use this access token when posting to the graph api.